# Example to follow for using Apache Camel Atmosphere Websocket component

Tags: apache-camel, atmosphere

Is there any example to follow for using Apache Camel Atmosphere Websocket component (atmosphere-websocket)? I am trying a basic thing; sending message from the client(Html5 Websocket) to the severe (Camel atmosphere- webscoket component) and resending back to the client.The severe i am using is vFabric tc Runtime 2.9.5.SR1 or Tomcat 7.0.50

My Route looks like this

```
from("atmosphere-websocket://localhost:8181/test1").to("log:body ${body}").to("atmosphere-websocket://localhost:8181/test1");
```

Javascript code

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8181/test1");    
ws.onopen = function (e) {       
   console.log("open"); 
}   
ws.onclose = function (e) {     
   console.log("close");   
}  
ws.onerror = function (e) {      
   console.log("error");   
}  
ws.onmessage = function (e) {        
   console.log("message");   
}
```

But i am getting an error

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8181/test1' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 403
```

From the log i can see that the route  and Atmospher framework started without any error

```
2015-03-10 16:13:14,391 [ost-startStop-1] WARN  IOUtils                        - META-INF/services/org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework not found in class loader

2015-03-10 16:13:14,435 [ost-startStop-1] INFO  AtmosphereFramework            - Atmosphere is using org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAnnotationProcessor for processing annotation

2015-03-10 16:13:14,436 [ost-startStop-1] INFO  DefaultAnnotationProcessor     - AnnotationProcessor class org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAnnotationProcessor$BytecodeBasedAnnotationProcessor being used

2015-03-10 16:13:14,482 [ost-startStop-1] INFO  AtmosphereFramework            - Auto detecting atmosphere handlers /WEB-INF/classes/

2015-03-10 16:13:14,484 [ost-startStop-1] INFO  AtmosphereFramework            - Auto detecting WebSocketHandler in /WEB-INF/classes/

2015-03-10 16:13:14,485 [ost-startStop-1] INFO  AtmosphereFramework            - Installed WebSocketProtocol org.apache.camel.component.atmosphere.websocket.WebsocketHandler 

2015-03-10 16:13:14,516 [ost-startStop-1] INFO  AtmosphereFramework            - Installed AtmosphereHandler org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework$5 mapped to context-path: /*

2015-03-10 16:13:14,516 [ost-startStop-1] INFO  AtmosphereFramework            - Installed the following AtmosphereInterceptor mapped to AtmosphereHandler org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework$5

2015-03-10 16:13:14,516 [ost-startStop-1] INFO  AtmosphereFramework            - Installing Default AtmosphereInterceptor

2015-03-10 16:13:14,517 [ost-startStop-1] INFO  AtmosphereFramework            -    org.atmosphere.interceptor.CorsInterceptor : CORS Interceptor Support
2015-03-10 16:13:14,517 [ost-startStop-1] INFO  AtmosphereFramework            -    org.atmosphere.interceptor.CacheHeadersInterceptor : Default Response's Headers Interceptor

2015-03-10 16:13:14,520 [ost-startStop-1] INFO  AtmosphereFramework            -    org.atmosphere.interceptor.PaddingAtmosphereInterceptor : Browser Padding Interceptor Support
2015-03-10 16:13:14,520 [ost-startStop-1] INFO  AtmosphereFramework            -    org.atmosphere.interceptor.AndroidAtmosphereInterceptor : Android Interceptor Support

2015-03-10 16:13:14,521 [ost-startStop-1] INFO  AtmosphereFramework            -    org.atmosphere.interceptor.HeartbeatInterceptor : Heartbeat Interceptor Support

2015-03-10 16:13:14,521 [ost-startStop-1] INFO  AtmosphereFramework            -    org.atmosphere.interceptor.SSEAtmosphereInterceptor : SSE Interceptor Support

2015-03-10 16:13:14,521 [ost-startStop-1] INFO  AtmosphereFramework            -    org.atmosphere.interceptor.JSONPAtmosphereInterceptor : JSONP Interceptor Support

2015-03-10 16:13:14,524 [ost-startStop-1] INFO  AtmosphereFramework            -    org.atmosphere.interceptor.JavaScriptProtocol : Atmosphere JavaScript Protocol

2015-03-10 16:13:14,524 [ost-startStop-1] INFO  AtmosphereFramework            -    org.atmosphere.interceptor.WebSocketMessageSuspendInterceptor : org.atmosphere.interceptor.WebSocketMessageSuspendInterceptor

2015-03-10 16:13:14,525 [ost-startStop-1] INFO  AtmosphereFramework            -    org.atmosphere.interceptor.OnDisconnectInterceptor : Browser disconnection detection

2015-03-10 16:13:14,525 [ost-startStop-1] INFO  AtmosphereFramework            -    org.atmosphere.interceptor.IdleResourceInterceptor : org.atmosphere.interceptor.IdleResourceInterceptor

2015-03-10 16:13:14,525 [ost-startStop-1] INFO  AtmosphereFramework            - Set org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereInterceptor.disableDefaults to disable them.

2015-03-10 16:13:14,532 [ost-startStop-1] INFO  AtmosphereFramework            - Using EndpointMapper class org.atmosphere.util.DefaultEndpointMapper

2015-03-10 16:13:14,532 [ost-startStop-1] WARN  AtmosphereFramework            - No BroadcasterCache configured. Broadcasted message between client reconnection will be LOST. It is recommended to configure the org.atmosphere.cache.UUIDBroadcasterCache

2015-03-10 16:13:14,532 [ost-startStop-1] INFO  AtmosphereFramework            - Default Broadcaster Class: org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster

2015-03-10 16:13:14,532 [ost-startStop-1] INFO  AtmosphereFramework            - Broadcaster Polling Wait Time 100

2015-03-10 16:13:14,532 [ost-startStop-1] INFO  AtmosphereFramework            - Shared ExecutorService supported: true

2015-03-10 16:13:14,532 [ost-startStop-1] INFO  AtmosphereFramework            - Messaging Thread Pool Size: Unlimited

2015-03-10 16:13:14,532 [ost-startStop-1] INFO  AtmosphereFramework            - Async I/O Thread Pool Size: 200

2015-03-10 16:13:14,533 [ost-startStop-1] INFO  AtmosphereFramework            - Using BroadcasterFactory: org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcasterFactory

2015-03-10 16:13:14,533 [ost-startStop-1] INFO  AtmosphereFramework            - Using WebSocketProcessor: org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor

2015-03-10 16:13:14,533 [ost-startStop-1] INFO  AtmosphereFramework            - Invoke AtmosphereInterceptor on WebSocket message true

2015-03-10 16:13:14,533 [ost-startStop-1] INFO  AtmosphereFramework            - HttpSession supported: false

2015-03-10 16:13:14,533 [ost-startStop-1] INFO  AtmosphereFramework            - Atmosphere is using DefaultAtmosphereObjectFactory for dependency injection and object creation

2015-03-10 16:13:14,533 [ost-startStop-1] INFO  AtmosphereFramework            - Atmosphere is using async support: org.atmosphere.container.Tomcat7Servlet30SupportWithWebSocket running under container: Undefined using javax.servlet/3.0

2015-03-10 16:13:14,535 [ost-startStop-1] INFO  AtmosphereFramework            - Atmosphere Framework 2.2.0 started.


2015-03-10 16:13:14,576 [ost-startStop-1] INFO  SpringCamelContext             - Route: route4 started and consuming from: Endpoint[atmosphere-websocket://localhost:8181/test1]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using an atmosphere-websocket endpoint, you should just specify the the path. There is a jave DSL sample in the unit test folder of the component.

And there is also an osgi sample code and its instruction at
https://github.com/elakito/testzone/tree/master/samples/osgi_camel_websocket_sample_route_bp
https://github.com/elakito/testzone/blob/master/samples/instruction_osgi_camel_websocket_sample_route.txt